# How to debug a file from current directory with Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I can see that this question has been asked multiple times already however, none of the solutions seems to be working anymore, forcing me to ask for the latest fix.

**Problem**

I have created a workspace in VS code with the following directory structure,

[image: VS Code directory structure]

- work__assignments (this is my main workspace folder in vs code)

  - assignment__1

    - data
    - modules
    - tests
  - assignment__2

    - data
    - modules
    - tests

"work__assignments" is my main workspace folder in the VS code. From this main workspace, I go to an assignment folder (e.g. **work__assignments > assignment__2 > modules**) and work on the respective code. However, when I try to debug the code in "**work__assignments > assignment__2 > modules**" the debugger loads from the main workspace folder (i.e. work__assignments), then it fails because it can't find other modules in the modules folder "**work__assignments > assignment__2 > modules**".

I have tried the following methods so far,

1. Updating the launch.json file and adding the line `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`,

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
}
```

2. Updating the launch.json file and adding the line `"cwd": ""`,

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": ""
}
```

3. Updating the launch.json file and adding the following lines,

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}"
    }
}
```

3. Updating the preferences

   [image: File > Preferences > Settings > Python > Execute in File Dir]

However, NONE OF THESE APPROACHES HAVE WORKED. Every time I debug the code, it launches into the workspace folder and not in the code folder. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am running the debugger using the "Debug Python File" button at the top right corner as shown in the picture below,
[image]

Comment: Try setting `cwd` to `"cwd": "./assignment__2"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure one of the following `cwd` in **launch.json**:

```json
    "cwd": "./assignment__2"
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

It should be noted that you need to debug the program from the **Run and Debug** panel to execute the configuration in **launch.json**.

[image]

##### A simple example

**Directory Structure and code**
[image]

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            // "cwd": "./hello"
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Debug results**
[image]

***Invalid configuration in `launch.json` if debug is selected from play button***
[image]

Comment: ahhh... turns out I was using the wrong button to run the "debugging". Never knew that there is this other button to run the debugging session.

Comment: So, is there a way to edit the config of the "Debug Python File" button?

Comment: @Matthieu H  It seems that it is not feasible for the time being. But there are several related GitHub links here you can follow.             [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20746]                [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11812]               [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20269]

Comment: @JialeDu Yes, this is faisable. You just have to set the `purpose` in launch.json, on the config you want the button to execute. Like this: `"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]`